# How to use gwan with wordpress installation through php-fpm?

Tags: php, wordpress, multithreading, g-wan

Is there an easy way to use wordpress through php-fpm using gwan?

Any use case, example of this to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we never succeeded in making `Zend PHP` run in a thread-safe manner, there's no way we can advise, unless someone makes a `Wordpress` port for `PH7`, which is both supported by G-WAN and thread-safe.

As multicore systems are now the norm (even on embedded platforms), either Zend will finally publicly release a thread-safe PHP, or people will increasingly look for alternatives.

---

Per the request of 'Nagi', here is the G-WAN PHP module sent 
to Zend for review:

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// php.c: G-WAN using PHP scripts
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// To build PHP5:
//
//    CFLAGS="-O3" ./configure --enable-embed --enable-maintainer-zts
//                             --with-tsrm-pthreads --without-pear
//    make clean
//    make
//    sudo make install
/*    Installing PHP SAPI module:       embed
      Installing PHP CLI binary:        /usr/local/bin/
      Installing PHP CLI man page:      /usr/local/php/man/man1/
      Installing PHP CGI binary:        /usr/local/bin/
      Installing build environment:     /usr/local/lib/php/build/
      Installing header files:          /usr/local/include/php/
      Installing helper programs:       /usr/local/bin/
        program: phpize
        program: php-config
      Installing man pages:             /usr/local/php/man/man1/
        page: phpize.1
        page: php-config.1
      Installing PEAR environment:      /usr/local/lib/php/
      [PEAR] Archive_Tar    - already installed: 1.3.7
      [PEAR] Console_Getopt - already installed: 1.3.0
      [PEAR] Structures_Graph- already installed: 1.0.4
      [PEAR] XML_Util       - already installed: 1.2.1
      [PEAR] PEAR           - already installed: 1.9.4
      Wrote PEAR system config file at: /usr/local/etc/pear.conf
      You may want to add: /usr/local/lib/php to your php.ini include_path
      /home/pierre/Downloads/PHP/php5.4-20/build/shtool install -c ext/phar/phar.phar /usr/local/bin
      ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/phar.phar /usr/local/bin/phar
      Installing PDO headers:          /usr/local/include/php/ext/pdo/       *//*      
   enabling the 'thread safety' --enable-maintainer-zts option 
   results in:
   error: 'tsrm_ls' undeclared (first use in this function)
*//*
// ---------------------------------------------------------
TEST VALIDATING THIS CODE WITH ONE SINGLE THREAD
(use 2 threads and the PHP runtime crashes)
// ---------------------------------------------------------
weighttp -n 100000 -c 100 -t 1 -k "http://127.0.0.1:8080/?php.c"

finished in 0 sec, 592 millisec, 168744 req/s, 48283 kbyte/s
requests: 100000 total/started/done/succeeded, 0 failed/errored
status codes: 100000 2xx, 0 3xx, 0 4xx, 0 5xx
traffic: 29299985 bytes total, 27599985 bytes http, 
         1700000 bytes data
// --------------------------------------------------------- */
#pragma include "/usr/local/include/php"
#pragma include "/usr/local/include/php/main"
#pragma include "/usr/local/include/php/TSRM"
#pragma include "/usr/local/include/php/Zend"
#pragma link "/usr/local/lib/libphp5.so"

#include "gwan.h" // G-WAN exported functions

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#include <php/sapi/embed/php_embed.h>
#include <php/Zend/zend_stream.h>
// ---------------------------------------------------------
static pid_t gettid(void) { return syscall(__NR_gettid); }
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// PHP
// ---------------------------------------------------------
static int ub_write(const char *str, unsigned int str_len TSRMLS_DC)
{
   puts(str); // this is the stdout output of a PHP script
   return 0;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------
static void log_message(char * message)
{
   printf("log_message: %s\n", message);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------
static void sapi_error(int type, const char * fmt, ...) { }
// ---------------------------------------------------------
static void php_set_var(char *varname, char *varval)
{
   zval *var;
   MAKE_STD_ZVAL(var);
   ZVAL_STRING(var, varval, 1);
   zend_hash_update(&EG(symbol_table), varname, strlen(varname) + 1,
                    &var, sizeof(zval*), NULL);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------
static char *php_get_var(char *varname)
{
   zval **data = NULL;
   char *ret = NULL;
   if(zend_hash_find(&EG(symbol_table), varname, strlen(varname) + 1,
                    (void**)&data) == FAILURE)
   {
      printf("Name not found in $GLOBALS\n");
      return "";
   }

   if(!data)
   {
      printf("Value is NULL (not possible for symbol_table?)\n");
      return "";
   }

   ret = Z_STRVAL_PP(data);
   return ret;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------
static int php_init(void)
{
   static int once = 0;
   if(once) return 0;

   once = 1;
   static char *myargv[2] = {"toto.php", NULL};
   php_embed_module.log_message = log_message;
   php_embed_module.sapi_error  = sapi_error;
   php_embed_module.ub_write    = ub_write;
   if(php_embed_init(1, myargv PTSRMLS_CC) == FAILURE)
   {
      printf("php_embed_init error\n");
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------
static void php_shutdown()
{
   php_embed_shutdown(TSRMLS_C);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------
static int php_exec(char *str)
{
   zval ret_value;
   int exit_status;
   zend_first_try
   {
      PG(during_request_startup) = 0;

      // run the specified PHP script file
      // sprintf(str, "include (\"% s \ ");", scriptname);

      zend_eval_string(str, &ret_value, "toto.php" TSRMLS_CC);

      exit_status = Z_LVAL(ret_value);
   } zend_catch
   {
      exit_status = EG(exit_status);
   }
   zend_end_try();
   return exit_status;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------
__thread char reply_num[8] = {0};
__thread pid_t tid = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if(!tid)
   {
      tid = gettid();
      s_snprintf(reply_num, 8, "%u", tid);
      php_init();
   }

   xbuf_t *reply = get_reply(argv);
   //php_set_var("argv", argv[0]);
   php_set_var(reply_num, "");

   char fmt[] = //"print(\"from php [$test]\n\");\n"
                "$reply%s = \"Hello World (PHP)\";\n";
   char php[sizeof(fmt) + sizeof(reply_num) + 2];
   s_snprintf(php, sizeof(php), fmt, reply_num);

   php_exec(php);

   xbuf_cat(reply, php_get_var(reply_num));
   return 200;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// End of Source Code
// ---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the statement that you could not run `Zend PHP` in a tread-safe manner? What do you mean by that exactly? PHP clearly states it supports thread-safety, and after reading what you wrote - it'd appear that you don't share the opinion of PHP team that PHP is thread-safe (if built with thread-safety flag). I think that the answer is either correct or absolutely misleading so I'm kindly asking for some clarification so I can decide whether G-WAN might fit my purposes.

Comment: When the Zend PHP runtime is used with 2 threads it crashes (even without libraries). One single thread works - but this defeats the purpose of multicore CPUs. We have requested several times assistance from Zend (even at an Expo) but never got any reply addressing the problem.

Comment: There's quite a few contributors to PHP project that are active here on SO, I must admit that I find it odd that you're experiencing this problem seeing that PHP is intended to work in a concurrent environment and works well with various web servers or even as a standalone CLI. I must admit I personally never contacted Zend themselves when I had issues, so if you're willing to explain the problem further, we might arrive to a conclusion in collaboration with PHP contributors?

Comment: @NB, you don't understand what the problem is: servers like Nginx are single-threaded (same story for CLI) and therefore won't have multi-thread issues (with or without PHP). We have even sent our PHP module source code to Zend, and never received any reply. Zend might change its positioning in the future, but PH7 looks good enough for us. BTW, Facebook bothered to write HipHop (renamed a few times), its own C++ implementation of PHP, for a reason (multi-thread, lack of support from the PHP company?).

Comment: Well, facebook's implementation doesn't even work properly and PHP does have multithreading capabilities and support, you just have to build it to enable that. nginx sends its http requests via fcgi to PHP-FPM so it's not even relevant whether nginx is multithreaded or not. I didn't find anything useful on your website in regards on how to run PHP (whether you used CLI version or FPM) and I tried to ask you what was used so I can see (for myself) what the problem really was. You mentioned a few times things lack, but *how* was the implementation attempted - no word about it.

Comment: Our PHP module sent to Zend was loading the PHP stack in the G-WAN environment - and if you believe you can fix the bugs they can't fix then drop us a line at gwan.com. How to use PHP with G-WAN is documented here: gwan.ch/faq#languages and the G-WAN archive comes with several PHP script examples.

Comment: @Gil I remember you made a piece of code public and stated that "if anyone manage to make this code run without crashing, G-WAN will support PHP" but I can't seem to find it. Maybe you should edit your answer and include that piece of code so more eyes can see?

Comment: @Nagi, I have added the PHP module code in the reply above.

Comment: @NB: it's relevant whether PHP is thread-safe or not because G-WAN is a multi-threaded program - unlike Nginx which is multi-process.

Comment: @Gil does this help in any way on getting PHP working with G-Wan? https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

Comment: Ethan, the link you present is for PHP7 which G-WAN supports in multithread mode since years: http://www.gwan.ch/faq#languages Zend PHP is another story because its runtime crashes when invoked from different threads.